# How can I display unicode in QGraphicsTextItem?

Tags: qt, unicode, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicstextitem

I would like to be able to display Unicode in `QGraphicsTextItem` (or a subclass of it).

The only way to set text in `QGraphicsTextItem` seems to be

```
setPlainText(text);
```

Trying

```
setPlainText(QString::fromUtf8("Caf\x00e9 Frap\x00e9"));
```

or

```
QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForName("utf8"));
setPlainText("Café Frapé");

QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForName("utf8"));
setPlainText("Caf\x00e9 Frap\x00e9");
```

I get:

```
Caf? Frap?
```

It seems that no matter what I do (which I am not sure is correct) I do not get the output right...

Do `QGraphicsTextItem` support unicode ? Is maybe the `setPlainText` function at fault - but then what are the alternatives ? (I looked into `setDocument` but it also sets plain text...)

Edit - copying the special characters inside the QGraphicsTextItem works, once on screen, but still unable to place any unicode from code.

Comment: The question suggested as a duplicate allows display of a single character, not a QString... and when posting my question I have found it, tried it, didn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you should use the

```
QGraphicsTextItem item.
item.setHtml( "Café Frapé" );
```

function instead of the mentioned. Read this [QGraphicsTextItem::setHtml](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicstextitem.html#setHtml).

Comment: I still get the same question marks

Comment: `setHtml("Caf&#x00e9; Frap&#x00e9;");` worked !

Comment: Of course I would still have the problem of converting non-html text into text that can be accepted. (template texts). I guess I would have to find a way to convert text to html ... ?

Answer (score 0):

In a class inheriting `QGraphicScene`, I used:

```
        QString text(QString::fromUtf8(xt.text));
        ...
        QGraphicsTextItem *t = addText(text = text.replace("\\n", "\n"), font);
```

The dot source is *utf8*:

```
digraph so {
Café -> Frapé
}
```

And the rendering:

[image]

You can find [here](https://github.com/CapelliC/loqt/blob/master/lqXDot/lqXDotScene.cpp#L496) the C++ code.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not see how to place a text inside a class deriving from QGraphicsTextItem...  I seem able to type the special characters inside the QGraphicsTextItem once displayed but I don't know how to enter them in code.